# How do I get more information in these event log entries? (values instead of parameter names)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-event-log

We occasionally see entries like these in the event log:

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.5.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x52157ba0
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.17415, time stamp: 0x54504ade
Exception code: 0xe053534f
Fault offset: 0x00014598
Faulting process id: 0x%9
Faulting application start time: 0x%10
Faulting application path: %11
Faulting module path: %12
Report Id: %13
Faulting package full name: %14
Faulting package-relative application ID: %15
```

How do I make these entries more informative? I'd love to see actual values instead of those %9-%15...